# How to edit SSRS 2008R2 Reports in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssrs

I'm a report writer who's been able to edit/update reports in Visual Studio 2008 (we use SSRS2008R2). I've just installed Visual Studio 2012 and when I go to convert my reports project it's not working as I appear to be missing a component.

Essentially - the project converts but in the solution explorer I see the message 'The application is not installed' under my project.

Beyond Visual Studio 2012 what else do I have to install to be able to edit rdl files in the visual designer like I could in Visual Studio 2008?

I have Visual Studio 2012 Premium + Expression Blend installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't! just try to install SQL Server 2012 and make sure that SQL Server Data Tool is installed then you can open it or you can open the report project using VS 2008